# The function setup () executes after ATmega328P wake up from the sleep mode

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, avr, embedded, reset

I am using ATmega328P in deep-sleep mode in Arduino IDE.
For wake up I am using PCINT. I can see it is working but `setup ()` also executes after wakeup.

Is it supposed to work that way?
If not, is it that ATmega328P is resetting?
Is it hardware problem or software?

Below added code and working.

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <Vcc.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 4
#define DATA_PIN A5
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

#define DIP_PIN1 20
#define DIP_PIN2 21
#define DIP_PIN3 5
#define DIP_PIN4 6
#define DIP_PIN5 7
#define DIP_PIN6 8
#define DIP_PIN7 9
#define DIP_PIN8 10
#define charge 0
#define power A4

#define DIP1 !digitalRead(DIP_PIN1)
#define DIP2 !digitalRead(DIP_PIN2)
#define DIP3 !digitalRead(DIP_PIN3)
#define DIP4 !digitalRead(DIP_PIN4)
#define DIP5 !digitalRead(DIP_PIN5)
#define DIP6 !digitalRead(DIP_PIN6)
#define DIP7 !digitalRead(DIP_PIN7)
#define DIP8 !digitalRead(DIP_PIN8)

RH_ASK driver;
Vcc vcc(1.0);
//Vcc vcc(3.1/3.2);
const int buttonPins[] = {A0, A1, A2};
unsigned long lastFire = 0, cycle_time, del, led_value = 0x00FFFF;
uint8_t button_state, count_send, test_count, port;
bool flag_low_charge, flag_send = false, flag_comm_done = true, flag_low_charge_indicator = true, flag_wakeup = false, Error = true;
uint8_t data[2] = {0};
unsigned int delay_time, loop_time;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (!driver.init())
  {
    Serial.println("init failed");
  }
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  pinMode(power, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(power, 0);
  digitalWrite(A0, 0);

  pinMode(DIP_PIN1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN5, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN6, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN7, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN8, INPUT_PULLUP);
  data[1] = data[1] | (DIP1 << 7);
  data[1] = data[1] | (DIP2 << 6);
  data[1] = data[1] | (DIP3 << 5);
  data[1] = data[1] | (DIP4 << 4);
  data[1] = data[1] | (DIP5 << 3);
  data[1] = data[1] | (DIP6 << 2);
  data[1] = data[1] | (DIP7 << 1);
  data[1] = data[1] | DIP8;
  delay_time = data[1] * 100;
  while (delay_time > 2000)
    delay_time = delay_time - 2000;
  pinMode(DIP_PIN1, INPUT);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN2, INPUT);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN3, INPUT);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN4, INPUT);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN5, INPUT);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN6, INPUT);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN7, INPUT);
  pinMode(DIP_PIN8, INPUT);
  pinMode(charge, INPUT);

//interrupt settings below

  DDRD |= B00000100;
  PORTD &= B11111011;
  DDRC &= B11110001;
  PORTC |= B00001110;
  PCICR |= B00000110;
  PCMSK2 |= B00000001;
  PCMSK1 |= B00001110;
}

void loop()
{
  goToSleep();
}


ISR(PCINT2_vect)
{
  flag_wakeup = true;
  digitalWrite(power, 0);
}

ISR(PCINT1_vect)
{
  if (!flag_comm_done)
  {
    return;
  }
  cli();
  port = PINC;
  flag_comm_done = false; 
  PORTD |= B00000100;
  test_count = port & B00001110;
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(power, 0);
  sei();
  delay(100); 
  flag_send = true;
}

void goToSleep()
{
  delay(100);
  PORTD &= B11111011;
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
  sleep_enable();
  sleep_mode();
  sleep_disable();
}
```

I have 3 push buttons on PCINT vector1(pulled up internally), common side of button is on another pin which I have set to output 0. I control this pin to disable interrupt from this buttons too. pin named "power" is to switch on and off transistor. does overcurrent through this pin cause reset ? (based on my calculation current consumed should be 35mA which is tolerable).

flag configuration works fine so you can neglect that,
also code in loop() works as desired after setup(). Flags I have set up in ISR also reflect in loop code perfectly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYihYT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by setup is run? If you are using Arduino please mention it. And post the code. How do you use PCINT? Most likely software problem.

Comment: edited that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment. Not answer but propositions. I had similar problem. To my case the problem was with watchdog. It messed with my interrupt, so I had to disable watchdog. *Maybe* something similar is happening to you.

You don't have code in loop, only sleep! Your code is on ISR's? Move the ISR code to loop.

1. Normal thing is to continue the code with EVERYTHING on memory active. Setup is NOT running after sleep. For some reason (software or hardware as you stated) you have reset.
2. I can't comment on electrical side.
3. On sleep I have slight different code. My source was [gammon](http://gammon.com.au/power). I strongly recommend you to try the examples from gammon.

```
void goToSleep()
{
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
  power_all_disable ();                        // power off ADC, Timer 0 and 1, serial interface
  sleep_enable();
  sleep_cpu();                             
  sleep_disable();
  power_all_enable();                          // power everything back on
}
```

Normally the Interrupt code should be tiny. Yours (`ISR(PCINT1_vect)`) is "big" and is messing with interrupts?

Example with tiny:

```
ISR(PCINT1_vect){
  interruptEvent++;
}
```

Can you get rid of the delays? They mess up with interrupts.

Comment: WDT could be the reason. https://gist.github.com/stojg/aec2c8c54c29c0fab407 gives some hints on WDT timeout event during the sleep.

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge, I don't think there is a problem with your code or approach

Deep sleep does not continue from the sleep, it starts with setup again. It’s basically a reset. If you have data you want to persist then you need to use RTC memory or flash.

yes it is supposed to work in that way

Comment: Is it documented anywhere in the datasheet/some references? Because it's not mentioned anywhere in the sleep modes of AVR that it will reset itself after any of the sleep modes.

Comment: you can refer this [LINK](https://www.electronicshub.org/esp8266-deep-sleep-mode/)@MituRaj

Comment: No. It's not mentioned anywhere in the link you gave that the Arduino RESETs after deep sleep. It won't because it beats the purpose of using sleep mode. It's mentioned in the datasheet of ATmega-128 that sleep mode RESUMES with the next instruction after waking up. Not RESETS.